# CSS - How would I align these 'li's to the right?

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3FWb.png

I've a problem with the message bubbles in my app, They won't align to the right, I've tried messing with displays, margins, floats, you name it.  I've decided to leave it up to the professionals.

Right now my hierarchy looks something like this:

```css
.Message {
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.Message>h5 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Message>ul {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Message>ul>li {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.Message>br {
  margin: 0px;
}

#MSGOUT {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

#MSGIN {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="Message" id="MSGIN">
  <h5>UserName</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>Message1</li>
    <li>Message2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way to do this is with flexbox

```css
.Message{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-items:flex-end;
}

ul{
list-style-type:none;}

h5{
margin:0}
```

```html
<div class="Message" id="MSGIN">
  <h5>UserName</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>Message1</li>
    <li>Message2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I put the flexbox into the ul instead of message since it wasn't working and that did the trick. TYSM for the help!

Comment: that's awesome.  If the answer works for you please accept it. Although, instead of placing the flex on the UL change the UL to a div and change the li's to either p tags or spans

Answer (score 1):

```css
.Message {
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.Message>h5 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Message>ul {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  direction:rtl;
}

.Message>ul>li {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.Message>br {
  margin: 0px;
}

#MSGOUT {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

#MSGIN {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="Message" id="MSGIN">
  <h5>UserName</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>Message1 longer</li>
    <li>Message2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you add "direction:rtl;" to the ".Message>ul" you will invert the way that the list is put together. That way the items are aligned on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Use "display: inline-block;" which allows to align a block element like an inline element with "text-align: right;"

Be careful however, inline elements create spaces if a space character is present next to it (since it's text). To avoid this, always make sure you only have html elements without tabs or spaces.
It is compatible since ie6 normally ;)

Sorry for translation.

```css
ul.MyList {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  display: block;
}

ul.MyList ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul.MyList li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.MyListContent {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.MyListContent.IAmBig {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="MyList">
  <li><span class="MyListContent">Content 0</span></li>
  <li><span class="MyListContent IAmBig">Content 1</span></li>
  <li><span class="MyListContent">Content 0</span></li>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="MyListContent">Sub Content 0</span></li>
    <li><span class="MyListContent">Sub Content 1</span></li>
  </ul>
  <li><span class="MyListContent">Content 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flexbox`

```css
.Message {
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.Message>h5 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Message>ul {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Message>ul>li {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.Message>br {
  margin: 0px;
}

#MSGOUT {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
 
#MSGIN {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="Message" id="MSGIN">
  <h5>UserName</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>Message1</li>
    <li>Message2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```